# What is the best test for SNV clustering?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, statistics, snp, allele

I am looking for a method to cluster single nucleotide polymorphisms based on clinicopathologic data (mainly receptor immunoistochemistry). So far, I've came up with only two that handle dummy variables as long as I want to examine minor allele presence or absence;

- Principal Component Analysis
- A priori (association rules)

Do you know of any papers supporting the abovementioned methods, or maybe suggest an alternative one?